# TFS get specific version , deleted workspace

Tags: tfs

in TFS 2010 I labeled a branch with label X , now on the other branch when I get specific version and select label X, my workspace is deleted completely its same even If I select overwrite all, any pointers what am I doing wrong. What I was expecting that by selecting label x on this branch it would be same as the branch I applied label on.

Comment: Can you paste your actual code?  I think I understand what you're asking, but not 100% sure.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you are expecting is not valid. You need to see the branch as a copy of your source code. When you put a label on that copy and than try to retrieve that label on the original, there are actually no files in the original that have that label set. Because the label is placed on the copy.

What would actually be the desired behavior, is that a `Get Specific version` would not show the label because it is not available on the original.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a label to a branch A, then it is only applied to the files in branch A, not anything in branch B. If you "get all the things at label A, from branch B", then it quite rightly returns nothing.

If you want the code that was in branch B at the point in time when the label was applied to branch A, then you need to look up the label to find the date/time it was applied, and then Get Specific Version (in Branch B) using the Date/Time as the point of reference for the code you want.

In future, consider applying the label to the root (parent of both branches) so that it is applied to all the files rather than being restricted to branch A.

Comment: Thanks for reply , the labels are being created by build definition, and scope is defined as String.Format("$/{0}", BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject) ,  so this should be from root ?

Comment: The basic idea behind this label exercise was to get changes done on bugfix branch to build branch  , So I labeled it from root , but it seems that there is no way you could get new changes across branch using label. What I did was I labeled from  root say label name as R of build and bugfix branch, then I added new changes in bugfix branch and added these changes to label R . now when I try to get specific version on build branch with label R , I dont get the changes done on bugfix.